# Retry Firestore if it fails

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Java application where I'm using Firestore. I was reading the "best practices" recommendations for Firestore related to transactions retries (https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#transactions_retries) .

It says:

> The Firestore SDKs and client libraries automatically retry failed
> transactions to deal with transient errors. If your application
> accesses Firestore through the REST or RPC APIs directly instead of
> through an SDK, your application should implement transaction retries
> to increase reliability.

That means "I shouldn't care/be worried" about failed transactions at all when using Firestore?

What kind of transactions might be handled (if there is a case)  with a separate retry logic, when using Firestore SDK or/and Client Libraries?

Is it even worth it to think about a custom retry logic in this scenario?

Comment: Is yours an Android application, or a server-side Java application? The SDKs for these implement transactions differently, so it makes a difference for the possible answer.

Comment: It is a spring boot java application (therefore server-side app). My understanding, there will be nothing to do, and Firestore will handle the retry with an exponential back-off retry algorithm.

Comment: Oh, that part is the same for both client-side and server-side SDKs. They auto-retry transactions in case of conflicting writes. Unless you already know of problems you might have with that behavior, it's typically not worth worrying about it.